# How To send mail with outlook using python in remote server where there is no outlook app and without fail of authentication using any protocol

Tags: authentication, outlook, smtp, devops, exchangewebservices

my orgnization has smtp disabled..one user(I) need smtp auth or send mail using any method..can you please elaborate all steps..

i need authentication to be successful to  send mail through outlook without using win32 and outlook app..tried all the steps..to enable checkbox authenticate smtp...please give any method not only smtp but any code in python use any protocol but the mail has to be sent..thank you

smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully. Contact your administrator.this is the error

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please check [ask]. "send me the codez" is too broad and will get downvoted and closed. [Edit] your question and include the code you've tried. There are plenty of examples on the web on how to send email in Python. If your admin really blocks all outgoing SMTP traffic, then talk to your admin. (BTW, it doesn't look like that, or you wouldn't even get to the authentication step.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Graph or EWS to be able to use OAuth.

Otherwise it is Outlook Object Model, but that means there must be a local user who has already logged in to Outlook and the Exchange account.